# Is it required to add a corelocation framework in my project, if I am using it in my own framework

Tags: ios, ipad, geolocation, ios-simulator, core-location

I am using coreLocationframework in my custom framework which I created,After integrating the framework to my project I got the below error after running the application

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MYFramework
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyBest", referenced from:
      -[Utility getCurrentLocation] in MYFramework
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

After that I just added the same corelocationframework in MY project as well then the error is not comming the code is working.

so I want to know what is the Reason behind this and it will happened if I added other frameworks also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you are building a static library or framework that relies on another framework, you have to link that framework into your framework and into the final project as well.

If you are publishing this framework somewhere for other people to use, you should have the instructions state that after they install your framework, they must also link `CoreLocation` as well.

Example:

```
MyFramework
--> Frameworks
   --> CoreLocation.framework

MyApp
--> Frameworks
   --> MyFramework.framework
   --> CoreLocation.framework
```

Comment: Thank You for your valuable response.

Answer (score 2):

At the heart of your framework is a static library that contains all the code in your framework. When you reference any of  core frameworks in the iOS SDK, they are dynamically linked to your projects. Because of this, any of the core frameworks you reference in your framework project will also need to be referenced in the application linking against your framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so that means adding a core framework in my project as well as MyFramework is not wrong or fault am I correct?